# Java store and list Json items

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a callback function and this function returns Json like this

```
{"user":"user1","message":"test message"}
```

...

```
{"user":"user2","message":"test message 2"}
```

...

I want to store this messages in one `ArrayList`, but I want to separate them by user, and I will list messages in another fragment.

Example:

> User clicks user1 and code is listing messages from user1.
>   User clicks user2 and code is listing messages from user2.

How can I store this messages by user and list by user in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> messages1 = new ArrayList<String>();
messages1.add("message11");
messages1.add("message12");
map.put("user1", messages1);
```

And so on.

Then, if you do:

```
ArrayList<String> messagesOfUser1 = map.get("user1");
```

You will receive all the messages for user1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a `Hashtable` for it. In a `Hashtable`, you can store an key-value-pair, so store the user and the Message-List, and get that List from the user name.

Example:

```
Hashtable<String, List<String>> table = new Hashtable<>();
table.put("user01", Arrays.asList("message01", "message02"));
table.put("user02", Arrays.asList("message03", "message07", "messageABC"));
```

If you then want to get the messages from one specific user, use:

```
public List<String> getMessages (String user)
{
    return table.get(user);
}
```

If the user doesn't exist, the function above will return `null`.

**EDIT:** Here is a more generic example with a `Hashtable`:

```
// Create your Hashtable
Hashtable<String, List<String>> table = new Hashtable<>();

// First, add the user with an empty List to your Hashtable
table.put("user", new ArrayList<String>());

// Now, add messages to the user
table.get("user").add("message 01");
table.get("user").add("message 02");

// Print all messages from the user
String user = "user";
System.out.println("Messages from user \""+user+"\": "+table.get(user));
```

Comment: HashTable cannot be resolved to a type I am getting this error.

Comment: @TolgayToklar It's `java.util.Hashtable`

Comment: Not worked : The import java.util.Hashtable is never used http://prntscr.com/4atmn7

Comment: @TolgayToklar What is the error in the line where you create the `Hashtable`?

Comment: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Comment: @TolgarToklar The Diamond Operator (`<>`) is only allowed since Java7; your Eclipse seems to compile your code below Java7. Please update Eclipse and set your source level to 1.7 or 1.8, or replace the diamond operator (`<>`) with `<String, List<String>>`

Comment: Thank you it fixed,but I have one more question I can't understand Arrays variable can you define it ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar `Arrays` is a class in the `java.util`-package. For more information see the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: I did like this: http://prntscr.com/4atvtr as you can see after each message I am listing the messages but table.get method is only returning last message.

Comment: @TolgayToklar You always add a new List in the Hashtable. You should create an `ArrayList`, add all your messages in there, and then store this `ArrayList` in the `Hashtable` (look at the other answers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58978/discussion-between-tolgay-toklar-and-user3755692).

Answer (score -1):

You can implement like :

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<String>> userMessage = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
messageList.add("message1");
messageList.add("message2");

userMessage.put("user1", messageList);

messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
messageList.add("message1");
messageList.add("message2");

userMessage.put("user2", messageList);
```

---

it might help you.